# Scrollbar In jQuery LightBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, lightbox

I want to display thumbnail images with scroll bar in ASP.net. This is my code sample.

```
      <h2 id="example">Example</h2>
<p>Click in the image and see the <strong>jQuery lightBox plugin</strong> in action.</p>
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image2.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image3.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image4.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image4.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image5.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image5.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image6.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image6.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image7.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image7.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image8.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image8.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image9.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image9.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image10.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image10.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image11.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image11.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image12.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Media Monitors All Pakistan Newspapers Web Hub!">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image12.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is image displaying now
[image]

but i want horizontal srollbar(move left-write) for the images
how can i implement scroll-bar in thumbnail show?? any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean you want to have a horizontal scrollbar for your `#gallery`? If that is the case, then you should set the width of your `#gallery` and set it as `overflow:auto;`. And you should set the `ul` to be wider than `#gallery` (to allow it scroll).

It would look like something like this:

```
#gallery {
    width:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}

ul { 
    width:600px;
}
```

JSFiddle rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/MHG4c/

It's very rough, but the basic idea is something like that.